# I have to check a checkbox twice before it runs the function. Vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to run a function every time an input field changes, it works for a text and email input fields but not for checkbox?

These are the HTML tags, when I change the text input field or the email input field, the function runs okay.. However, when I check the box I have to click it twice before it takes effect, the first click keeps the `show_pending` false.

```
        <input type="text" v-model="search.name" @input="getBusinessUsers()" placeholder="Search by name" class="form-control">
        <input type="email" v-model="search.email" @input="getBusinessUsers()" placeholder="Search by email" class="form-control">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="checkbox" v-model="search.show_pending" @input="getBusinessUsers()">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="checkbox">Show pending users</label>
```

This is the data model:

```
    data() {
        return {
            users: [],
            search: {
                name: null,
                email: null,
                show_pending: false,
            },
        }
    },


        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="checkbox" v-model="search.show_pending" @input="getBusinessUsers()">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="checkbox">Show pending users</label>
```

And this is the function I'm trying to run:

```
        getBusinessUsers(){
            this.users = [];
            let component = this;

            let pageNum = this.pageNum;
            let search = this.search


            var endpoint = '/businesses?page='+pageNum;


            Object.keys(search).forEach((key) => (search[key] == null) && delete search[key]);//remove empty params

            Object.keys(search).forEach(function(item) {
                console.log(item, search[item]);
                endpoint += "&" + item + "=" + search[item];
            });//append non empty params to endpoint to fetch all users
            console.log(endpoint);

            this.$http.get(endpoint).then(response => {
                console.log(response.data);
                let pagination = response.data.meta.pagination;

                this.pageCount = pagination.total_pages;
                response.data.data.forEach(function (user) {
                    user.edit = false;
                    component.users.push(user);
                })
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

All I needed is use the `@change` instead of `@input`. So this:

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="checkbox" v-model="search.show_pending" @change="getBusinessUsers()">
```

instead of:

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="checkbox" v-model="search.show_pending" @input="getBusinessUsers()">
```